# Создание ссылки на скачивание файла использую python

Tags: python

Есть бот, который работает с файлами и обрабатывает их. Но из-за ограничений телеграмма не получается отправлять конечный файл назад. Единственное что смог придумать это отправлять ссылку, которая будет позволять скачать файл при нажатии. Но вот как это сделать не знаю. Есть какие нибудь библиотеки, которые помогут реализовать данную задачу используя python.

Comment: Т.е. вам нужна библиотека, которая куда-то разместит файлы и даст ссылку на скачивание?

Comment: @gil9red Файл после создания размещается на сервере. Нужно формировать ссылку на его скачивание от туда. Я знаю что можно подобное написать используя html, но вот насчет чего то подобного в python я не знаю

Comment: html недостаточно, вообще, только с html такого не сделать. html это разметка страницы, а то, что вы описываете это вебсервер, который и может вернуть html

Comment: @gil9red я это понимаю. Я и спрашиваю есть ли для этого библиотека

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/642790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/kek.png')
def download():
    return send_file('kek.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=12000)
```

Файл будет доступен по адресу `http://ваш_ip:12000/kek.png`
например `http://255.255.255.255:12000/kek.png`